# Android CountDownTimer and AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, countdowntimer

I want the AlertDialog to show up once the CountDownTimer finishes but I get an error when I try to do it. Does anyone have a solution or a better way of doing it?

```
{
new CountDownTimer(60000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
 mTextField.setText(":" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }
 public void onFinish() {
 mTextField.setText("GAME OVER");
 mTextField.setTextSize(50);

     AlertDialog.Builder ADB = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
     ADB.setTitle("GAME OVER")
        .setMessage(R.string.app_name)
        .setNeutralButton("PRESS BACK AND START GAME TO PLAY AGAIN", null)
        .show();
 }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: also let us know what error you are getting.. post your logcat here

Comment: Post this code in a separate mehtod:  AlertDialog.Builder ADB = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
     ADB.setTitle("GAME OVER")
        .setMessage(R.string.app_name)
        .setNeutralButton("PRESS BACK AND START GAME TO PLAY AGAIN", null)
        .show();
 than call that method in finish, I hope this will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually your code perfect i run it but replace

```
 AlertDialog.Builder ADB = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
```

by
where replace Game by your activityname

```
 AlertDialog.Builder ADB = new AlertDialog.Builder(Game.this);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
 new Thread()
   {
       public void run()
       {
            sleep(3000);
           AlertDialog.Builder successfullyLogin = new Builder(LWM.this);
            successfullyLogin.setCancelable(false);
           successfullyLogin.setMessage("Successfully Login !").show();
           }
   };
```